# Why does subscription status is down when using pglogical in AWS aurora?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

I have two Aurora postgresql clusters 11.9 and 13.4 deployed in AWS. I followed the instruction https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/part-2-upgrade-your-amazon-rds-for-postgresql-database-using-the-pglogical-extension/ to setup the replica from cluster 11 to cluster 13.

The node, replica_set and subscription are all created successfully in both clusters. However, when I check the subscription status in the target database, the status is down:

```sql
=> select subscription_name, slot_name, status from pglogical.show_subscription_status();
 subscription_name |                   slot_name                   | status
-------------------+-----------------------------------------------+--------
 ams_subscription1 | pgl_____ngine_ams_mast2d01c59_ams_subsc050888 | down
(1 row)
```

In the target database log, I can see below error:

```
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC::@:[16329]:LOG: background worker "pglogical apply 16400:3226503298" (PID 29403) exited with exit code 1
2022-03-01 06:35:49 UTC::@:[16329]:LOG: background worker "pglogical apply 16400:3226503298" (PID 1453) exited with exit code 1
2022-03-01 06:38:29 UTC::@:[16329]:LOG: background worker "pglogical apply 16400:3226503298" (PID 10318) exited with exit code 1
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

in the source database log:

```
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33688):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26786]:ERROR: replication origin "pgl_____ngine_ams_mast2d01c59_ams_subsc050888" does not exist
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33688):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26786]:STATEMENT: SELECT pg_catalog.pg_replication_origin_session_setup('pgl_____ngine_ams_mast2d01c59_ams_subsc050888');
BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ COMMITTED;
SET session_replication_role = 'replica';
SET DATESTYLE = ISO;
SET INTERVALSTYLE = POSTGRES;
SET extra_float_digits TO 3;
SET statement_timeout = 0;
SET lock_timeout = 0;

2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33688):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26786]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33684):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26784]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33684):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26784]:LOG: unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33686):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26785]:LOG: could not receive data from client: Connection reset by peer
2022-03-01 06:34:29 UTC:10.74.105.225(33686):amsMasterUser@AMSEngine:[26785]:LOG: unexpected EOF on client connection with an open transaction
----------------------- END OF LOG ----------------------
```

I can see there are errors in both source and target instances. But I can't figure out what could be the issue.

Comment: I am experiencing the same issue with RDS PostgreSQL. Does anyone know what could be the reason for this?

Comment: I am having the same issue, any update?

Answer (score 0):

### Root Cause

It is a very weird state and not sure how to overcome it and undertand the root cause but I've managed to resolve this with following steps.

For us, reason was shutting down source and target databases and that was somehow resulting into this out of sync status.

Note : If your subscription status is `replicating` and source/target are out of sync then run the command mentioned in #additional note only and no need to apply resolution.

### Resolution

If your subscription status is `down`

- Drop pglogical extension
- Create pglogical configuration for your publisher and subscriber databases again.

### Additional Note

Last step will put subscription back in `replicating` state fine for new entries but lag might still be there.

So to ensure both the source and target tables are in sync, run this below command

```
SELECT pglogical.alter_subscription_resynchronize_table('${SUBSCRIPTION_NAME}', '${SCHEMA_NAME}.${TABLE_NAME}');
```

In a matter of few minutes both the tables have data in sync.